# Doubling a selection in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

If you make a selection of the header element in the [post body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/339911) in mobile web you can see that the text is doubled:

> [image: selected header]

Looks like a font white shadow. Shadow for unselected header is not visible.
Difference is better visible in the original image. Click on the image from the post to see it in full size.

Comment: What is doubled? The text is different. I don't get what you try to highlight.

Comment: Yeh that's just how text-shadow appears with selected text. Not much SE can do about that

Comment: @ShadowWizard see updated picture (look into the original image by clicking) to compare selected vs unsellected text.

Comment: @Cai is this not handled by something like css-style?

Comment: @alexolut sure, [they could remove the shadow on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027452/css-to-remove-text-shadow-on-select-highlight-text-mozilla), but it's not a bug, it's just how browsers render the shadow and selection together.

Comment: Your edit makes a good point though... It's not really visible when it isn't selected, so not sure why it's even there

Comment: @Cai full web is not affected, hence I think it is on SE side, not browser.

Comment: @alex the mobile site has different CSS, you can switch to the mobile theme on desktop and see the same behaviour. The shadow itself *is* added by SE, I'm just saying the way it shows with a selection is down to the browser.

Comment: @Cai yep. At the first time I saw it on desktop after switching to mobile theme, but as far as I recall some bugs with mobile web on desktop was considered as not-bugs, so I decided to check the behaviour on my phone. After that I posted a report with the image from mobile device.